# problem with posting data on atlas from NODE EXPRESS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

So i was trying to run this basic products posting program and i think is right!!! I am trying to POST this with the help of atlas
i removed my password from the url const.

all i am getting is catch statement even tho i think it is right.
what's the problem with it ??

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const url ='mongodb+srv://meon:<password>@cluster0-3lxqo.mongodb.net/products_test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';



const createP = async (req,res,next) =>{
    const newP = {
        name : req.body.name,
        price : req.body.price
    };
    const client = new mongoClient(url,{useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology : true});

    try{
        await client.connect();

        const db = client.db();
        const result = db.collection('products').insertOne(newP);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        return res.json({msg : 'not sharing data'});

    };
    client.close();

    res.json(newP);

};
```

Comment: What does the error looks like?

Comment: the catch statement is printing.

Comment: That is not what I am asking. We can't help you if you just say that you have an error. You might console.log your error just after your catch and include it in your question.

Comment: It looks like you did not post a lot of questions. Do you need help editing yours into [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?